# ASP.NET Identity Fluent NHibernate bind the mappings:

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-identity

https://nhibernateidentity.codeplex.com/documentation
In this docs is written:

First you need install the package:

```
 PM> Install-Package NHibernate.Identity
```

After you installed you need to bind the mappings:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IdentityUser>())
```

How and where? Can someone try to explain. I want to use Nhiberant with Identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IdentityUser>())` has to be added where you create your Config for the SessionFactory with FluentNHibernate.
It should look like this

```
var config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Mappings(mappingConfig => 
                      mappingConfig.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IdentityUser>());
```